# is it possible having two types of checkout process for two different themes in one website

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, onepage-checkout, store-view

Magento store using a custom theme for desktop view. Now it is required to create a mobile theme for that store. So I just **created a mobile theme** inside the custom package.

The theme for **desktop view is using the onepage checkout process**.
But I am asked to **setup a multi-step checkout process** in the mobile theme.
How is it possible to have **two types of checkout process for a single store** ?
Or is there any **alternative option** to achieve this functionality ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a **responsive theme** for both desktop and mobile with and integrated **responsive one-step-checkout**, not a sepparate mobile theme.

Google appreciates better one responsive theme (for both desktop and mobile) in place of 2 sepparate themes (one for desktop and one for mobile).

2 types of checkout for same store view in Magento in not possible.

If you still want to have 2 sepparate themes you can do it in this way:

- create a sepparate subdomain for mobile: **mobile.yourwebsite.com**
- add in htaccess a mobile redirect according to device
- create a multistore structure in Magento with 2 sepparate websites: one for desktop and other for mobile. Each website will have his own store view but use same root category.
- set for the desktop site the base url as: yourwebsite.com and the theme for desktops. You can also enable one step checkout for this website
- set for the mobile site the base url as mobile.yourwebsite.com and the theme for mobiles. No template exception needed for theme because the redirection according to device is done in htaccess. You can now turn off one step checkout module for this website.

Comment: Thanks @Alain Banutz for the reply. But I am asked  to create another theme for mobile devices rather than using the responsive theme.

Comment: It is actually possible to run two separate checkouts in one store. I have done it to A/B test a onestepcheckout and the core checkout. This was a long time ago, so I don't recall any real details. The main crux was to ensure they have separate urls (example /checkout/onepage and checkout/onestep).

Comment: My answer is for Magento default One step checkout module which can be enabled per website, not per store view. If you use extensions than indeed you can have more than one checkout on same store view if the url's are different and the extensions don't conflict with each other, although I wouldn't recommend that.